# plotting autoscaled subplots with fixed limits in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

What's the best way in matplotlib to make a series of subplots that all have the same X and Y scales, but where these are computed based on the min/max ranges of the subplot with the most extreme data? E.g. if you have a series of histograms you want to plot:

```
# my_data is a list of lists
for n, data in enumerate(my_data):
  # data is to be histogram plotted
  subplot(numplots, 1, n+1)
  # make histogram
  hist(data, bins=10)
```

Each histogram will then have different ranges/ticks for the X and Y axis. I'd like these to be all the same and set based on the most extreme histogram limits of the histograms plotted. One clunky way to do it is to record the min/max of X/Y axes for each plot, and then iterate through each subplot once they're plotted and just their axes after they're plotted, but there must be a better way in matplotlib.

Can this be achieved by some variant of axes sharing perhaps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086724/matplotlib-linked-x-axes-with-autoscaled-y-axes-on-zoom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Matplotlib/Pyplot: How to zoom subplots together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200586/matplotlib-pyplot-how-to-zoom-subplots-together)

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html

http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html

quoting the last link:

> Fernando Perez has provided a nice top level method to create in
>   subplots() (note the “s” at the end) everything at once, and turn off
>   x and y sharing for the whole bunch. You can either unpack the axes
>   individually:
>
> ```
> # new style method 1; unpack the axes
> fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
> ax1.plot(x)
> ```
>
> or get them back as a numrows x numcolumns object array which supports
>   numpy indexing:
>
> ```
> # new style method 2; use an axes array
> fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
> axs[0,0].plot(x)
> ```

If you have an old version of `matplotlib` the following method should work (also quoting from the last link)

> Easily creating subplots In early versions of matplotlib, if you
>   wanted to use the pythonic API and create a figure instance and from
>   that create a grid of subplots, possibly with shared axes, it involved
>   a fair amount of boilerplate code. Eg
>
> ```
> # old style
> fig = plt.figure()
> ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
> ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
> ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223, sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
> ax3 = fig.add_subplot(224, sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
> ```

Comment: Just posted a similar answer, but your more complete. I woud just put a little more attention to the new style, as it's more clean and preferred to the old one.