# new pythonic style for shared axes square subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Related to: [plotting autoscaled subplots with fixed limits in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612610/plotting-autoscaled-subplots-with-fixed-limits-in-matplotlib)

I would like to make a set of subplots that are all on the same scale, using the `subplots` new compact style, as in http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots and have them be square.

I tried:

```
fig, axes = subplots(numplots, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True, adjustable='box', aspect='equal')
```

But I found that these keyword arguments are not implemented in the `subplots` wrapper. What's the way to do it?

To reiterate, the goal is simply to have *shared* axes, so that all the data are on the same scale, and have the plots be square.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use `adjustable='box-forced'` instead of `adjustable='box'`.

As @cronos mentions, you can pass it in using the `subplot_kw` kwarg (additional keyword arguments to `subplots` are passed on to the `Figure` not the `Axes`, thus the need for `subplot_kw`).

Instead, I'm going to use `setp`, which basically just does `for item in sequence: item.set(**kwargs)`.  (All matplotlib artists have a `set` method that can be used similar to matlab's `set`.)

Which one is the "better" approach will depend on what you're doing. A lot of people would argue that `setp` is very "unpythonic", but I don't see the problem with it.

As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
plt.setp(axes.flat, aspect=1.0, adjustable='box-forced')

axes[0].plot(range(50))

plt.show()
```

[image]

I forget the reason for the two different adjustable box styles, at the moment.  I remember that I found it really confusing the first time I came across it, and I dug through the code and there was some obvious reason for it... I can't remember what that reason was at the moment, though.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you refer to suggests a subplot_kw

```
fig, axes = subplots(numplots, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True, subplot_kw=dict(adjustable='datalim', aspect='equal'))
```

However the shared axes seem to require datalim as adjustable, the plots are scaled correctly but not square. If you leave out the shared axes, then "box" works. Your call.

Comment: But I want the axes to be shared *and* the plots to be square. How can that be achieved? As you note, `datalim` and `equal` aspect do not solve the problem. This must have a very simple solution?

Comment: I am not sure, but I am afraid it is not possible since one gets `ValueError: adjustable must be "datalim" for shared axes` if one tries to use "box" and "equal".

Comment: so what is a way to make a square subplot in matplotlib with shared axes? It's such a trivial plot and matplotlib so powerful, there must be a way to do it?

Comment: Got mislead by the error message ("must be"). @JoeKington got it right, `adjustabe='box-forced'`, does the job. Works also fine with the `subplot_kw` dictionary.