# Aspect ratio of a plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I try to change my aspect ratio in python. I know this has been discussed in many other cases (e.g. with figaspect), but I don't get it like I want to have it. If I use figaspect, I get the error:

`'Figure' object is not callable`.

Without it I have this code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(y_test1, linewidth=0.5, linestyle="-", label='Test1')
ax.plot(y_test2, linewidth=0.5, linestyle="-", label='Test2') 
legend = ax.legend(loc='right center',prop={'size': 5}, shadow=True, fontsize='medium')
plt.xlabel('images')
plt.ylabel('error')
plt.grid()
plt.axis([0,100, 0, 20])
```

It works, but I need an other aspect ratio. How do I get a plot that is three times wider than high?

Comment: Please give some sample code so we can run it on our machines. thanks

Comment: Try `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1,3))`.

Comment: Thanks Max, it works! It looks so easy, I just thought too complicated..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aspect ratio in subplots with various y-axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907062/aspect-ratio-in-subplots-with-various-y-axes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the aspect ratio in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965743/how-can-i-set-the-aspect-ratio-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options. As suggested in the comments, you can increase the figure size manually, making sure the width is three time bigger than the height.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(height, height*3))
```

If you want to use [`figaspect`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.figaspect.html#matplotlib.figure.figaspect) you can do the following:

```
from matplotlib.figure import figaspect

w, h = figaspect(1/3)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(w,h))

plt.show()
```

This creates a *figure* which is 3 times wider than it is tall and gives:

[image]

You can also change the *axes* aspect ratio using `ax.set_aspect()`. This will *not* change the figure size:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_aspect(1/3)

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're best helped with something like this:

```
ax.set_aspect('auto')
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html)
This, however, changes the axis aspect ratio. as @MaxPowers points out, you can also alter the `figsize`of your subplots.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the figure size directly to produce varied sizes as wanted.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(10, 3), sharex=True, sharey=True, constrained_layout=True)
```

Hope this could help.