# Pyplot: Shared axes and no space between subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is related to (or rather a follow-up) to [new pythonic style for shared axes square subplots in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629994/new-pythonic-style-for-shared-axes-square-subplots-in-matplotlib).

I want to have subplots sharing one axis just like in the question linked above. However, I also want no space between the plots. This is the relevant part of my code:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
plt.setp(ax1, aspect=1.0, adjustable='box-forced')
plt.setp(ax2, aspect=1.0, adjustable='box-forced')

# Plot 1
ax1.matshow(pixels1, interpolation="bicubic", cmap="jet")
ax1.set_xlim((0,500))
ax1.set_ylim((0,500))

# Plot 2
ax2.matshow(pixels2, interpolation="bicubic", cmap="jet")
ax2.set_xlim((0,500))
ax2.set_ylim((0,500))

f.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
```

And this is the result:
[image]

If i comment out the two plt.setp() commands, I get some added white borders:
[image]

How can I make the figure look like my first result, but with axes touching like in the second result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT: The fastest way to get your result is the one described by @Benjamin Bannier, simply use

```
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
```

The alternative is to make a figure that has a width/height ratio equal to `2` (as you have two plots). This may be advisable only if you plan including the figure in a document, and you already know the columnwidth of the final document.

You can set width and height in the call to `Figure(figsize=(width,height))`, or as a parameter to `plt.subplots()`, in inches. Example:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True,figsize=(8,4))
fig.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1,0,0)
```

Screenshot:[image]

As @Benjamin Bannier points out, as a drawback you have zero margins. Then you can play with `subplot_adjust()`, but you must be careful with making space in a symmetric way if you want to keep the solution simple. An example could be `fig.subplots_adjust(.1,.1,.9,.9,0,0)`.

Comment: Your `subplots_adjust` hides the axes which might not be what is needed. I'd suggest `subplots_adjust(hspace=0)` which exclusively removes the space between the panels.

Comment: Yupp, seem to have the wrong mental picture, I always mix these two up.

Comment: If you look in my original question, I do use `subplots_adjust(wspace=0)` and it does **not** kill the space. However, your solution using an appropriate figure size and carefully adjusting the subplot margins symmetrically **does** work and is sufficient for my purposes! I am still irritated, tough, that my original code does not work...

Comment: I found my mistake! The setp() lines should happen **after** the matshow() commands (which makes sense in the pyplot world, I guess), then it works as you suggested! Thanks.