# Subplots with equal and shared axes in Pyplot.jl

Tags: matplotlib, julia

As the title suggests, I'd like to make a plot in Pyplot.jl with equal (circles look like circles) and shared (plots have same limits) axes.

I get errors whenever I try to use `setp()` as in [new pythonic style for shared axes square subplots in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629994/new-pythonic-style-for-shared-axes-square-subplots-in-matplotlib) or use the `subplots()` command and access the figure and axis elements that are returned. I am also not very familiar with PyPlot or Python in general.

As an example, I'd like to have

```
using PyPlot

u = linspace(0, 2pi, 100)
unit_x = cos(u)
unit_y = sin(u)

A = [1 2; 0 2]
transf = [unit_x unit_y] * A'

subplot(121)
plot(unit_x, unit_y)
axis(:equal)

subplot(122)
plot(transf[:, 1], transf[:, 2])
axis(:equal)
```

display plots side-by-side with the same axes so that they are directly comparable. Right now this gives

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZx2G.jpg

I have also tried returning the axis limits and setting the left plot to equal the right, but they are not returned correctly after calling `axis(:equal)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you maybe looking for

```
fig, ax = subplots(1,2, sharey = true)
ax[1,1][:plot](unit_x, unit_y)
ax[2,1][:plot](transf[:, 1], transf[:, 2])
```

I always tend to think the fig/ax notation is more helpful for doing subplots, but YMMV... This gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This got me most of the way there. I mostly couldn't figure out the syntax for the `fig`/ `ax` notation. On Julia 0.3.11 with PyPlot 2.1.0 and PyCall 1.0.3, I got an error using two indices for the axes, so I used `ax[1]` and `ax[2]`. An `axis(:equal)` call at the end resized everything appropriately.

Comment: How can you add a title to the individual subplots? Writing `ax[1,1][:title]("Example...")` doesn't work.