# Difference between sharey='row' and sharey='True'

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I am thinking on a plot that contains 3 rows and 4 columns, where:

There are 3 dependent variables to plot: `Y1`, `Y2` and `Y3`, versus a common `X` independent variable, for 4 cases of study:

[image]

In this situation there is:

1) a sharing of `y` axis when going from `case i` to `case i+1`

2) a sharing of `x` axis within a `case i`

Thus, in principle, one would think that the following code will produce the desired plot (result shown in the upper image):

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=3,\
                         sharex=True, sharey=True,\
                         subplot_kw=dict(adjustable='box-forced'))
```

where the `adjustable='box-forced'` is just to ensure that the subplots are squared, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629994/new-pythonic-style-for-shared-axes-square-subplots-in-matplotlib).

When I try to plot `Y1` versus `X` for case 1:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=3,\
                         sharex=True, sharey=True,\
                         subplot_kw=dict(adjustable='box-forced'))

pad = 5
axes[0][0].annotate('Case 1', xy=(0.5, 1), xytext=(0, pad),
                xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
                 size='large', ha='center', va='baseline')

axes[0][1].annotate('Case 2', xy=(0.5, 1), xytext=(0, pad),
                xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
                 size='large', ha='center', va='baseline')

axes[0][2].annotate('Case 3', xy=(0.5, 1), xytext=(0, pad),
               xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
                size='large', ha='center', va='baseline')

axes[0][3].annotate('Case 4', xy=(0.5, 1), xytext=(0, pad),
                xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
                 size='large', ha='center', va='baseline')

#
axes[0][0].set_ylabel('Y1', fontsize=10)
axes[1][0].set_ylabel('Y2', fontsize=10)
axes[2][0].set_ylabel('Y3', fontsize=10)

E_C_I =  np.array([-941.23658347, -941.23685494, -941.23467666])
V_C_I =  np.array([ 61.66341, 62.342903,  67.9311515])
E_14 =  np.array([-941.22938469, -941.23583586, -941.23605613])
V_14 =  np.array([ 54.65693125,  58.47115725, 60.8626545 ])
P_C_I =  np.array([ 2.20068119,  1.33328211,  -4.28370285])
P_14 =  np.array([ 8.16605135,  7.54737315, 0.3909309 ])


axes[0][0].scatter(V_C_I, E_C_I, marker='^', color='red', label='Calcite I')#, s=100)
axes[0][0].scatter(V_14, E_14, marker='o', color='green', label='Calcite I')#, s=100)

axes[0][0].set_ylim(bottom=-941.238, top=-941.229)

plt.tight_layout()
axes[0][0].ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.show()
sys.exit()
```

Everything seems fine:

[image]

I have forced the plot to `axes[0][0].set_ylim(bottom=-941.238, top=-941.229)`

When I try to plot `Y2` versus `X` for `Case 1`, the following code should work:  I am basically doing the same as before, but adding the `axes[1][0]` plotting instruction:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=3,\
                         sharex=True, sharey=True,\
                         subplot_kw=dict(adjustable='box-forced'))

pad = 5
axes[0][0].annotate('Case 1', xy=(0.5, 1), xytext=(0, pad),
                xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
                 size='large', ha='center', va='baseline')

axes[0][1].annotate('Case 2', xy=(0.5, 1), xytext=(0, pad),
                xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
                 size='large', ha='center', va='baseline')

axes[0][2].annotate('Case 3', xy=(0.5, 1), xytext=(0, pad),
               xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
                size='large', ha='center', va='baseline')

axes[0][3].annotate('Case 4', xy=(0.5, 1), xytext=(0, pad),
                xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
                 size='large', ha='center', va='baseline')

#
axes[0][0].set_ylabel('Y1', fontsize=10)
axes[1][0].set_ylabel('Y2', fontsize=10)
axes[2][0].set_ylabel('Y3', fontsize=10)

E_C_I =  np.array([-941.23658347, -941.23685494, -941.23467666])
V_C_I =  np.array([ 61.66341, 62.342903,  67.9311515])
E_14 =  np.array([-941.22938469, -941.23583586, -941.23605613])
V_14 =  np.array([ 54.65693125,  58.47115725, 60.8626545 ])
P_C_I =  np.array([ 2.20068119,  1.33328211,  -4.28370285])
P_14 =  np.array([ 8.16605135,  7.54737315, 0.3909309 ])


axes[0][0].scatter(V_C_I, E_C_I, marker='^', color='red', label='Calcite I')#, s=100)
axes[0][0].scatter(V_14, E_14, marker='o', color='green', label='Calcite I')#, s=100)

axes[0][0].set_ylim(bottom=-941.238, top=-941.229)

axes[1][0].scatter(V_C_I, P_C_I, marker='^', color='red', label='Calcite I')#, s=100)
axes[1][0].scatter(V_14, P_14, marker='o', color='green', label='Calcite I')#, s=100)

axes[1][0].set_ylim(bottom=-4.4, top=8.4)

plt.tight_layout()
axes[0][0].ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.show()
sys.exit()
```

The result is that the `axes[0][0]` plot has changed its scale, and therefore no data is shown:

[image]

I have forced both `axes[0][0]` and `axes[0][1]` to show the region where indeed there is data:

```
axes[0][0].set_ylim(bottom=-941.238, top=-941.229)
axes[1][0].set_ylim(bottom=-4.4, top=8.4)
```

However, no data is shown on the `axes[0][0]` plot. Why is this happening?

**Update:** The difference between `sharey='row'` and `sharey=True` has been clarified in the excellent @DavidG's answer. However, I have tested the difference between `sharex='col'` and `sharex=True` and I have noticed that:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=3,\
                         sharex=True, sharey='row',\
                         subplot_kw=dict(adjustable='box-forced'))
```

produces the following:

[image]

However,

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=3,\
                         sharex='col', sharey='row',\
                         subplot_kw=dict(adjustable='box-forced'))
```

kind of leaves some space between the columns, and breaks the `adjustable='box-forced'` declaration for the subplots to be squared:

[image]

I was wondering why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have applied the share y axis to *all* of the subplots using the argument `sharey=True`.

There is a handy argument of `sharey='row'` which will make each row of subplots share the same y axis. Therefore, change the creating of the figure to:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=3,\
                         sharex=True, sharey='row',\
                         subplot_kw=dict(adjustable='box-forced'))
```

This will then give the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You have very well pointed out the difference between `sharey='row'` and `sharey=True`.  However, I have noticed that the difference between `sharex=True` and `sharex='col'` produces kind of a different result (please see updated post).

Comment: I have changed the title of the post, so that it is presented as a more general case