# How to get the max ylim of multiple histograms

Tags: matplotlib

I'm plotting histogram for a group of data, the histograms looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that, every histogram has its own `ylim`. I want to set them to the same, so I can compare them directly, something like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

I can set the plotting axis by `plt.axis([-5,360,0,3000])`, but this also require I know the axis range before hand. How can I get such value?

Comment: Do you means `ax.get_ylim()`?

Comment: @HYRY, yes, but how can I know the limit beforehand? Or I should first `ax.get_y_lim()`, and then plot in the new range again?

Comment: Look at `sharey`. Here's an example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plotting autoscaled subplots with fixed limits in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612610/plotting-autoscaled-subplots-with-fixed-limits-in-matplotlib)

Comment: also `ax.set_ylim([min, max])` will set them to what ever you want.